# How to filter 1D vector data using a cut-off wavelength in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, butterworth

I am trying to apply a high-pass filter to a signal (column or row vector) consisting of 1-pixel-wide lines taken from a black-and-white image. I know the resolution of the image (`res` in the code below, given in mm/pixel). How can I filter these line data in MATLAB to discard certain low frequencies (waviness) or large wavelengths, say >10 mm, using a Butterworth filter or any other?

Line data are not centered at zero.

```
Fs = 1; % I do not know if this assumption is correct for the image.
Fn = Fs/2; % Nyquist frequency.

lambda = 10; % Cut-off wavelength in mm, given.

samples_in_lambda = lambda/res; % divide by resolution to get samples.

fc = 1/samples_in_lambda; % Cut-off frequency from lambda.
```

I tried : `[z, p, k] = butter(9, fc/fn, 'high'); % I see the filter is high pass on plotting.`

Can I filter the line data using the above given and assumed values? If not, is there a way that I can filter the data using a cut-off wavelength?

Answer (score 0):

The highest linear spatial frequency you can represent without aliasing is 1 wave cycle per 2 pixels. This means a spatial Nyquist frequency of 1 wave cycle per `2*(res*1e-3)` meters, or `1000/(res*2)` reciprocal meters. (Confront this with temporal frequencies, which are measured in reciprocal seconds a.k.a. hertz).

In terms of wavelengths: the shortest wave you can represent without aliasing is 2 pixels long per wave cycle. This means a spatial "Nyquist wavelength" of `res*2e-3` meters. (Confront this with temporal "wavelengths" a.k.a. periods, which are measured in seconds.)

If you want to set a cutoff wavelength of 10 mm, that corresponds to a spatial frequency of 100 reciprocal meters. Since the `butter()` function takes as its second input argument (`Wn`, the cutoff frequency) an arbitrary fraction of the (spatial) Nyquist frequency (the MATLAB documentation calls it "half the sampling rate"), you merely need to set `Wn=100/(1000/(res*2))`, i.e. `Wn=res/5`.

Even though your definition of the spatial sampling frequency is not quite correct (unless you are intentionally measuring it in reciprocal pixels), your final result ended up being equivalent to `Wn=res/5`, so you should be fine using the call to `butter()` that you indicated.